# Row/column counter in 'apply' functions

Tags: r, apply

What if one wants to `apply` a functon i.e. to each row of a matrix, but also wants to use as an argument for this function the number of that row. As an example, suppose you wanted to get the n-th root of the numbers in each row of a matrix, where n is the row number. Is there another way (using `apply` only) than column-binding the row numbers to the initial matrix, like this?

```
test <- data.frame(x=c(26,21,20),y=c(34,29,28))

t(apply(cbind(as.numeric(rownames(test)),test),1,function(x) x[2:3]^(1/x[1])))
```

P.S. Actually if *test* was really a matrix :  `test <- matrix(c(26,21,20,34,29,28),nrow=3)`  , rownames(test) doesn't help :(
Thank you.

Comment: Note that in your example you don't need the apply!

Comment: Yes, I can see that :) Actually I wanted to draw some lines on a plot at positions associated with the line number.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What I usually do is to run `sapply` on the row numbers `1:nrow(test)` instead of `test`, and use `test[i,]` inside the function:

```
t(sapply(1:nrow(test), function(i) test[i,]^(1/i)))
```

I am not sure this is really efficient, though.

Comment: The only downside of this is that if the function is complicated, you can't easily reuse it with different dataframes.  But I agree passing a vector of the positions and then using that to index is the way to go.

Comment: Careful -- if nrow(test) == 0 then this will loop from 1 to 0 and the test[i,] will fail

Answer (score 4):

If you give the function a name rather than making it anonymous, you can pass arguments more easily.   We can use `nrow` to get the number of rows and pass a vector of the row numbers in as a parameter, along with the frame to be indexed this way.

For clarity I used a different example function; this example multiplies column x by column y for a 2 column matrix:

```
test <- data.frame(x=c(26,21,20),y=c(34,29,28))
myfun <- function(position, df) {
    print(df[position,1] * df[position,2])
}

positions <- 1:nrow(test)
lapply(positions, myfun, test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in the case of a matrix, you don't even need `apply`. Just:

```
test^(1/row(test))
```

does what you want, I think. I think the `row()` function is the thing you are looking for.

Comment: I agree, but look at the comments below the question.

Comment: Yes, but I still think the "row()" function is exactly what you need.

Comment: Still I can't see how can I give a `lines` command like this  
`lines(test[i,],c(i,i))` without an apply or a for loop.   `lines(CI,row(CI))` doesn't work

Comment: If you give me an example command which does what you want, I'll see if I can re-write it. I'm still not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is a great answer! It even works on data frames!

Answer (score 2):

`cbind()`ing the row numbers seems a pretty straightforward approach. For a matrix (or a data frame) the following should work:

```
apply( cbind(1:(dim(test)[1]), test), 1, function(x) plot(x[-1], main=x[1]) )
```

or whatever you want to plot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confuse so excuse me if I get this wrong  but you want work out n-th root of the numbers in each row of a matrix where n = the row number. If this this the case then its really simple create a new array with the same dimensions as the original with each column having the same values as the corresponding row number:

```
test_row_order = array(seq(1:length(test[,1]), dim = dim(test))
```

Then simply apply a function (the n-th root in this case):

```
n_root = test^(1/test_row_order)
```