# R apply function with multiple parameters

Tags: r

I have a function `f(var1, var2)` in R. Suppose we set `var2 = 1` and now I want to apply the function `f()` to the list `L`. Basically I want to get a new list L* with the outputs

```
[f(L[1],1),f(L[2],1),...,f(L[n],1)]
```

How do I do this with either `apply`, `mapply` or `lapply`?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545879/row-column-counter-in-apply-functions/28102021#28102021

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Just pass var2 as an extra argument to one of the apply functions.

```
mylist <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
myfxn <- function(var1,var2){
  var1*var2
}
var2 <- 2

sapply(mylist,myfxn,var2=var2)
```

This passes the same `var2` to every call of `myfxn`.  If instead you want each call of `myfxn` to get the 1st/2nd/3rd/etc. element of both `mylist` and `var2`, then you're in `mapply`'s domain.

Comment: but note that `myfxn` may be vectorised, in which case one should use `myfxn(unlist(mylist), var2=var2)`

Comment: The original example was unclear but seemed to be to be non-vectorized.  Point well taken, however.

Comment: Is the a way to make this work as a function "on the fly?"  Something like this:
`sapply(mylist, function(var1, var2) {
 var1*var2
  }, var=thisvar2)`
But I get an error that argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments

Comment: @emudrak I think the problem there is jus that you're naming the argument you pass `var` instead of `var2`. R can't divine what you mean.

Answer (score 83):

If your function have two vector variables and must compute itself on each value of them (as mentioned by @Ari B. Friedman) you can use `mapply` as follows:

```
vars1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
vars2 <- c(10, 20, 30)
mult_one <- function(var1, var2)
{
   var1*var2
}
mapply(mult_one, vars1, vars2)
```

which gives you:

```
> mapply(mult_one, vars1, vars2)
[1] 10 40 90
```

Comment: One upvote for generalizing, even with a simple and clear example.

Comment: `mapply` will also recycle if `vars1` has a single element. For example when `vars1 <- 3`,  `mapply(mult_one, vars1, vars2)` returns `30 60 90`. This is useful when you want to use `lapply` over the second argument of a function.

Comment: Does `mapply` work with more than 2 arguments in the fucntion ?

Answer (score 15):

To further generalize @Alexander's example, `outer` is relevant in cases where a function must compute itself on each *pair* of vector values:

```r
vars1 <- c(1,2,3)
vars2 <- c(10,20,30)
mult_one <- function(var1, var2)
{
   var1*var2
}
outer(vars1, vars2, mult_one)
```

gives:

```r
> outer(vars1, vars2, mult_one)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   20   30
[2,]   20   40   60
[3,]   30   60   90
```