# R - sapply function with multiple arguments

Tags: r, arguments, sapply

I have a similar, but not quite the same question to [R apply function with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827299/r-apply-function-with-multiple-parameters)

I have a dataset with two variables RSHIFTSTART and RSHIFTEND (amongst other variables).
These variables contain times eg. 23:30:00 or 00:00:00.
I'd like to replace RSHIFTSTART and RSHIFTEND with NA wherever BOTH variables are zero ie. '00:00:00'.

I've written a function which I think may do the job:

```
# Change '00:00:00' to NA where both variables are '00:00:00'
zeroTime=function(x,y) {
    if (x=='00:00:00' & y=='00:00:00') {
        replace(x,x=='00:00:00',NA)
        replace(y,x=='00:00:00',NA)
    }
}
```

My question is how to apply this function to update the dataset's variable ie. supplying two arguments to it. I tried:

```
sapply(rosterSample$RSHIFTSTART,rosterSample$RSHIFTEND,zeroTime)
```

but this syntax is incorrect. Perhaps I'll be restricted to changing just one variable per call ie. RSHIFTSTART or RSHIFTEND, that's OK.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Pete

Comment: how about `?mapply`: "mapply is a multivariate version of sapply"

Comment: `sapply` or `mapply` is not the right approach here. R uses *pass-by-value*, not *pass-by-reference*. That means `zeroTime` does not modify its `x` and `y` arguments outside the scope of the function. @Karl's answer is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks flodel, that makes sense, if the functions just pass by value and have to return the updated variable. Thomas thanks for that too - I hadn't seen that question in my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
rosterSample <- data.frame(RSHIFTSTART=c('00:00:00', '01:00:00', '00:00:00'), RSHIFTEND=c('10:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ind <- with(rosterSample, RSHIFTSTART=='00:00:00' & RSHIFTEND=='00:00:00')
rosterSample$RSHIFTSTART[ind] <- NA
rosterSample$RSHIFTEND[ind] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks Karl - that should do the trick. Thanks for the sample code too, much appreciated.