# Establish covariance matrix in R

Tags: r

I am using two for loops to establish a covariance matrix in R. I have 2 data vectors and a covariance function f(x) between every 2 data points. My code is like this:

```
r12=function(x1,x2,H){
  ra12= matrix(0,length(x1),length(x2))
  for (i in 1:nrow(ra12)) 
  {
    for (j in 1:ncol(ra12)) 
    {
      raed12[i,j]=fx(x1[i]-x2[j],H)
    }
  }
  return(raed12)
}
```

How can I make this code faster?

Comment: For starters, how about changing your inner for loop so as to only compute the lower or upper triangle of the covariance matrix?

Comment: Is `fx` vectorized?  If so, your code looks like longhand for computing an outer product.  See the help for `outer`.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I had originally posed that as an answer, but I think that there are two different vectors, i.e. it may be a rectangular Gram matrix when x1 != x2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an `sapply()` solution, passing in [multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827299/r-apply-function-with-multiple-parameters) assuming `fx()` is vectorized:

```
r12 <- function(x1,x2,H){
          return(fx(x1-x2,H))
       }
mat <- sapply(vector1, r12, vector2, H)
```

Comment: I really thank you a lot, you have saved me a lot of time really

Comment: It seems I do not need to Vectorize the function , also when I vectorize it is gives an error , can you explain that ?