# apply function for multiple fixed parameter in R

Tags: r, apply, self

I have created a function, say `myfunc`, which has 4 parameters, say `para1`, `para2`, `para3` and `para4`. In my problem, `para1` is a matrix, `para2` is a real number, `para3` is a vector, and `para4` is a real number. **The function returns a list.** I have defined the function in the following manner :

```
myfunc <- function(para1, para2, para3 = NULL, para4 = 100){
          Body ## Body of the function
          return(list("A" = a, "B" = b, "C" = c)
          }
```

Now, let `lambda <- c(2,3,6,10)`. I am trying to write a code so that the function outputs the following :

```
myfunc(my_data, 2, my_vec, 100)
myfunc(my_data, 3, my_vec, 100)
myfunc(my_data, 6, my_vec, 100)
myfunc(my_data, 10, my_vec, 100)
```

This can be easily done by a for loop, but **I was thinking if we can use `apply` or `sapply` or `tapply` function** for this purpose. **So, keeping the other parameters fixed, I want outputs of the same function with different values (viz. the values in `lambda`) of `para2`.** Can this be done ?

---

I found a quite similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6827299/12036804), and saw some answers. I followed those answers, but I'm getting an error. I wrote the following code :

```
myfunc <- function(para1, para2, para3 = NULL, para4 = 100) { Body }
para1 <- my_data
para3 <- my_vec
para4 <- 100
lambda <- c(2,3,6,10)

sapply(lambda, myfunc, para1=para1, para3, para4=para4)
```

Can I please get some assistance ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the lambda

```
lapply(lambda, function(x) myfunc(my_data, x, my_vec, 100))
```

If we are not using lambda function

```
lapply(lamdba, myfunc, para1 = my_data, para3 = my_ec, para4 = 100)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I used the first line that you wrote, and it's working fine! Can you please tell me what you meant by your second line (i.e. "If we are not using lambda function") ?

Comment: @Kolmogorov I meant the lambda/anonymous fucntion not as `lambda` you defined.  It is the `function(x) ..` i.e. the funciton created on the fly without assigning it to a object

Comment: Oh. Understood. Thank you!