# Condensing 3D data into a Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, reshape, multidimensional-array

So I am sorting a matrix one row at a time in descending that is 130X130, and I want to create a new matrix where the row name is the same, but the each sorted row column names are where the data was and the data in parenthesis next to the according column name. Its kind of like creating a psuedo3D array of the dimension 130x130x2 and then condensing it into a 130x130 matrix without column names.  Here's a smaller example.

> Example

```
        A   B   C   D   
    A   14  82  18  50
    B   39  95  27  19
    C   60  40  32  15
    D   70  31  69  31
```

This is what I want

```
    A   B(82)   D(50)   C(18)   A(14)
    B   B(95)   A(39)   C(27)   D(19)
    C   A(60)   B(40)   C(32)   D(15)
    D   A(70)   C(69)   B(31)   D(31)
```

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

First, recreate your data:

```
x <- read.table(text="
        A   B   C   D   
    A   14  82  18  50
    B   39  95  27  19
    C   60  40  32  15
    D   70  31  69  31", header=TRUE)
```

---

Two `apply()`s, a `paste()` and a `matrix()`, and the rest is details:

```
o <- apply(x, 1, order, decreasing=TRUE)
v <- apply(x, 1, sort, decreasing=TRUE)

matrix(paste(names(x)[o], t(v)), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] "B 82" "D 50" "C 18" "A 14"
[2,] "B 95" "A 39" "C 27" "D 19"
[3,] "A 60" "B 40" "C 32" "D 15"
[4,] "A 70" "C 69" "B 31" "D 31"
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on a comment by Jeff Allen, this can be further simplified to:

```
t(apply(x, 1, function(x){s <- order(x, decreasing=TRUE); paste(names(x)[s], x[s])}))

  [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
A "B 82" "D 50" "C 18" "A 14"
B "B 95" "A 39" "C 27" "D 19"
C "A 60" "B 40" "C 32" "D 15"
D "A 70" "C 69" "B 31" "D 31"
```

(Since this has only one `apply` it should be even faster.)

Comment: @JeffAllen Based on your comments, I have simplified it further to have a single `apply`

Comment: I like the last one. You can also replace `paste(...)` with `sprintf("%s(%d)", names(x)[s], x[s])` to match the OP's output format.

Answer (score 3):

I'm hoping someone will propose a vectorized solution, but here's one option:

```
sortTab <- function(tab){
    for (i in 1:nrow(tab)){
        #Get the order of the elements in the current row
        ord <- order(tab[i,], decreasing=TRUE)

        #get the associated column names and values with this ordering      
        res <- paste(colnames(tab)[ord], "(", tab[i,ord], ")", sep="")

        #assign back to the data.frame
        tab[i,] <- res

    }
    tab
}
```

And a test using your data:

```
txt <- textConnection("        A   B   C   D   
    A   14  82  18  50
    B   39  95  27  19
    C   60  40  32  15
    D   70  31  69  31")
tab <- read.table(txt)

> sortTab(tab)
      A     B     C     D
A B(82) D(50) C(18) A(14)
B B(95) A(39) C(27) D(19)
C A(60) B(40) C(32) D(15)
D A(70) C(69) B(31) D(31)
```

Comment: Upon further review, here's a discussion on the limitation I encountered with `apply()` which forced a `for` loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545879/row-column-counter-in-apply-functions?rq=1. I'm not entirely sure that would help with the performance here. Perhaps someone can suggest an improvement.

Comment: Out of interest, what limitation of `apply` are you referring to?

Comment: I would have liked something like the following: `apply(tab, 1, function(x){x <- paste(order(x)...)})`. But without passing by reference, that's not going to work out.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I've used this idea in my edited answer.